# how to insert data to gridview from textbox use list<>

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

**I'm using ASP.NET C#.**

I have a **TextBox**, **a DropDownList**, and a **submit Button**.

I will ***input*** data to the **TextBox** and **press Submit**.

How do I ***display*** the data that I input *from the textbox*, *into the DropDownList*, **using List<>** ?

If I replace the DropDownList with a GridView, what has to change?

this is class I defined it in app_cod

```
public class CarEntity :System.Web.UI.Page{
public string CarNumber { get; set; }
public string CarModel { get; set; }
public string Brand { get; set; } }
```

I have Problem here,how I can complete this code?

```
protected void addbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<CarEntity> carlist = new List<CarEntity>
    CarEntity car = new CarEntity();
    car.CarNumber();

    carlist.Add(car);
}
```

---

```
<asp:GridView ID="grid1" runat="server" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="table tbody_tr th clear" CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="2">
   <Columns>
      <asp:BoundField DataField="CarNumber" HeaderText="Car Number" />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="CarModel" HeaderText="Car Model" />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="Brand" HeaderText="Brand" />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="Action" HeaderText="Action" />
   </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Either you will have to use 'State Management' technique or insert data into database and bind table data into your grid view.

Comment: why CarEntity class inherit from System.Web.UI.Page ?

Comment: This article and additional resources from the links will put you on the right track: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb498195.aspx

Comment: Actually this is the first time I use a list <>
 because the managers asked me this
So I do not know what the correct way to use it is to take data from a textbox to gridview without data Source

Comment: Well to add to a dropdown would be something similar too: drpCars.Items.Add(new ListItem("Value", "Text"));

Comment: @eslam - You are contradicting your own question. You say how to bind the dropdown\ gridview using **List<>** but you have only asked user to enter single item not a collection.

Comment: @RahulSingh
when I enter data in text1 and text2 and select item from dropdown and click on button
I need to see the enterd data display in gridview
that's I need

Comment: @eslam - Yeah that's exactly what I mean, it will provide data form single `CarEntity` object right? What about `List<CarEntity>` how you will get other data? Or you mean each time you want to add data to list or dropdown?